# Node' \n' error when creating localhost server

Tags: node.js, http

I'm following along in a [MongoDB course](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/10gen/M101JS/2014_October/courseware/Week_1_Introduction/) and came to a basic Node Hello world server tutorial:

[image]

Basically it just displays Hello World on localhost:8000

So I typed out the code below and when I tried to run it, ran into the following error:

[image]

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.end("Hello, World"\n);
});

server.listen(8000);

console.log("Server running at http://localhost:8000");
```

If I remove the \n it will work fine, just curious as to how does the teacher get his to work with it and no errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a typo. It should be: `response.end("Hello, World\n");`.